# Function to replace zero by Null

Tags: presto, trino

Is there a function in presto that does something like `coalesce` but replacing `zero` by `null` ?

I have this query:

```
select avg(value) from tbl
```

the outuput is:

```
0.23
0.30
0
0.90
```

And I want this:

```
0.23
0.30
null
0.90
```

Comment: select NULLIF(0, avg(value)) from tbl,   https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?highlight=NULLIF#id1

Answer (score 0):

There is a `IF` expression in Trino (formerly PrestoSQL).   https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if